# RJ11 for ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet

My laptop's RJ45 Ethernet socket has failed. Is it possible to use the RJ11 socket to connect to the network via some kind of adapter? Would Windows be able to use the RJ11 to connect to the internet?

What I have: a (presumably) working RJ11 socket in my laptop. An ethernet cable with RJ45 connectors at each end. A virgin media cable modem that one end of the ethernet cable goes into.

I hope that makes sense! I barely know what I'm talking about here!!

Comment: And barely know how to read the Help link at the top of the site.

Comment: You can not use an RJ11 connector for ethernet. Search amazon for a usb to ethernet adapter.

Comment: Technically you could, you just can't use the one in your laptop for that.

Comment: Ever heard of dial-up?

Comment: Does the laptop have a USB 2.0 port? The adaptor is less than $10 and the right way to go.

Answer (score 12):

The required equipment for you to make a network connection using your **modem** will cost more than a USB NIC, and have worse performance. Don't even try.

Comment: Yeah. Instead, get a USB Ethernet adapter.

Comment: I see... I just found this: [link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003Q85EEA/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) Would that be the better solution?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go.

Comment: @sall If your laptop is new enough to have a USB3 port a USB3-gigabit adapter would give significantly better performance.  Otherwise yes.

Comment: @DanNeely - a laptop that still has an internal dialup modem would be lucky to have USB2 ;)

Comment: Cisco Ethernet router with modem card.. Connect 56k modem to router, connect ethernet to router... Hmm, connectivity over PPP at 56kbit/s.  Yeah, buy a USB ethernet (or PCMCIA ethernet adapter.)

Comment: @MarkHenderson Dell still offers them on some Latitude models.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not all related to the connector (RJ11), but the electronic inside, that is connected to the modem for PSTN line. Default (no passive POE for example) 10/100 Ethernet uses only 2 pairs of wires, and requires just four "vias" in the connector.

@Signal15 PSTN modems are still used, some satellite connections use the PSTN line with a modem for the uplink, less and less of course, but is not that "archaic" that no one will have.

Answer (score 0):

The RJ11 jack is for dial-up connection and connects to the modem inside your laptop. So if you have a phone line you can connect to the internet through it but the speed is obviously just as slow as one can expected for dial-up (56/115/231kbps). Theoretically it's also possible to use RJ11 as ethernet and connect 2 computers, since what you need is just a way to transfer bits between 2 points. But in reality there's nothing I can find that uses RJ11 for transmission